# Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'products/(?P<product>[-\\w]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to link to a page in the Django admin; I'm using the slugField to do so. I have created a base URL in the main 'urls.py' file which includes a namespace. I then have declared my product urls in the `urls.py` file, which directs to my template and view.

### index.html

```html
{% for item in products %}
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <div class="box">
    {% if item.image_one %}
    <div class="image">
      <img src="{{ item.image_one.url }}" alt="{{ item.name }}">
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="content">
      <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
      <a href="{% url 'products:product' item.slug %}" class="button">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<product>[-\w]+)/$', views.product, name='product'),]
```

### views.py

```
def product(request, product):

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product)

    return render(request, 'products/product.html',{
        'product':product,
})


 def index(request):

     products = Product.objects.all()

     return render(request, 'products/index.html',{
         'products': products,
})
```

### rendered HTML on index.html page:

```
<section id="products">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="/media/temp-image.png" alt="product name">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h4>product name</h4>
            <a href="/products/product-name/" class="button">View Product</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="/media/temp-image_uQcyyVv.png" alt="Another product">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h4>Another product</h4>
            <a href="/products/another-product/" class="button">View Product</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It looks like one of your products is missing a slug. Please post a) your `index` view and b) inspect element and post the rendered html on the index page.

Comment: @BrianDant Please see edits

Comment: I edited your post. Can you please re-read it to ensure that we're on the same page? I noticed that the regular expression in the title of your post does not match that in your `urls.py`. `[-\\w]}` vs. `[-\w]`. In any case, if you're trying to intercept requests that would normally go to the admin, as I write in the edit near the top, we should consider changing that. There's better ways to do this.

Comment: Yes we are on the same page. I noticed the difference in URL pattern but even when i changed this nothing changed.

Comment: I have tried almost everything so anything you can suggest would be welcomed

Comment: Also, the error that you are seeing indicates that you don't have a `slug` on one of the `products`. Can you confirm that they all have a `slug`? And, if this is failing, how is it that you could output the rendered html? Does it not fail every time?

Comment: The `[-\\w]+` in the title of your post would indicate an issue with the regex, no? It would be looking for a literal \. You need the latter version (which is actually what your `urls.py` contains. (Why then would `reverse` be getting the other one?) Here's the proper regex: https://regex101.com/r/1QloEf/1

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why the url reverse fails, but you should not do what you are doing with the admin. Instead, change your `urls.py` to not mimic the admin:

```
url(r'^(?P<product>[-\w]+)/$', views.product, name='my-product-view')
```

Then, in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'my-product-view' item.slug %}" class="button">View Product</a>
```

If that doesn't work, ensure that you can `reverse` by hand. Get a Django shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

Then try to reverse the url with the id from one of your objects:

```
>>> from django.urlresolver import reverse
>>> aproduct = Product.objects.first()
>>> reverse('my-product-view', args=(aproduct.slug,))
```

What I do above in the shell is more or less what happens behind the scenes with your `{% url %}` tag, so this will give us some insight into where the problem lies.
If that doesn't work, you've got a problem with your settings. Confirm that your `INSTALLED_APPS` contains the app in which this `urls.py` lives.

Finally, the error you see would seem to indicate that you're missing a slug on one of your products ("reverse for product with *no arguments* ..."). Confirm that this is not the case by iterating in the shell over your products:

```
>>> for p in Products.objects.all():
>>>     if not p.slug: 
>>>         print(p)
```

Comment: Shell is working just fine, i can confirm app is added to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Did you change the name of your view?

Comment: Copy your shell session into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping. Turns out I had referenced the URL string without the slug perimeter elsewhere in the document I was trying to open and therefore it was causing an error.

Appreciate the help and support